# Hibernate Multitenancy with Discriminator approach

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant, hibernate-4.x

Hibernate [has not yet supported](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4632) the multi-tenancy implementation by Discriminator Strategy approach. We were thinking about implementing this strategy in our project. But we had some doubts about the query performance in general. Would the query performance be worse than the Separate Database/Schema approach, since in this case the query is ran over a single schema of data of many tenants? Or are there any ways for improving the query performance in this case, apart from creating indexes?

We are considering the Discriminator approach as it is better to do a backup & restore if data is in single schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It potentially could affect performance for sure.  The "single backup/restore" argument is only really pertinent in the case of some form of catastrophe; typically you want restores to be as granular (read least disruptive) as possible.

As for performance you could (depending on your database) look at leveraging partitioning on this discriminator value.  Databases that support partitioning generally take partitions into considerations when building query plans.  Although some require that the partition values be supplied as literals rather than parameters which can be tricky sometimes.